# Why are similar questions treated differently?

Tags: discussion

This question

[Is Ramanuja's alleged re-interpretation of "kapyasam" from the Chandogya Upanishad correct?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/is-ramanujas-alleged-re-interpretation-of-kapyasam-from-the-chandogya-upanish)

was put in hold as not pertaining to Hinduism

while

[Why did Adi Sankaracharya compare the color of Ishwara's eyes to that of monkey's nates?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/why-did-adi-sankaracharya-compare-the-color-of-ishwaras-eyes-to-that-of-monkey)

is out there.

This kind of arbitrariness degrades the quality of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not well-done by the community. I voted to reopen. The anti-Sankaracharya Q remains open and anti-Ramanuja is closed.

Comment: I suggest you to read the cloase reason before jumping to conclusions. You are at your best to see posts with anti Shankara and Anti Ramanuja point of view when they are not.

Comment: You are not the only one who voted to close . You are the one that provided a reason though an insubstantial one. Still not bad.  Thanks for the suggestion and your observation about my inclinations. @sarvabhouma

Answer (score 2):

I am the one who cast the first close vote. I explained the reason properly in the comment and it is still there.It was closed with a **custom reason**. If you have not read that I will explain the reason again.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic **because the answer is provided along with question and asks some more answers**. **It uses body to answer the title by making statements** like "Sankara's translation alone seems to be correct according to panini's grammar. "kapi" cannot be "kam pibati" (the drinker of water = Sun)" and adding answer like statements like both Shankara and Ramanuja are wrong. So, there is nothing else to answer the question.

The problem is you are using title of the body as your question and body of the question to answer your own question. It is **not** allowed on a site like Stack Exchange. Questions and answers should be separate.

You were giving your answer why Shankaracharya or Ramanujacharya are right or wrong in the question itself which should be an answer. Whether it is right or wrong that is a different matter.

Read [What type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers.

Hence, it is off-topic. Other question linked in the question was asking in a proper way. There is no different treatment because it was questioning some famous acharaya. The difference is due to the way it was asked.

Even in the recent edit, it is modified to add a sentence

> This question clarifies this
>
> > [Why did Adi Sankaracharya compare the color of Ishwara's eyes to that of monkey's nates?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17695/5212)

Questions are not to be used to clarify other existing questions.

I hope that you learn [How to ask a good question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "I hope that you learn How to ask a good question."  The person who wrote this would do well to learn which questions he should try to close.

Comment: I know it very well. I didn't hope I would say that statement a person who asked more than 100 questions and access to moderator tools. That page is generally shown to newbie users. But seriously, you should show some effort before while posting a question.

Comment: "But seriously, you should show some effort before while posting a question" I have complained to the moderator about this.